# Disable JQuery datatable checkbox when selected by user

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, datatable

I would like to disable the datatable checkbox (which is the first column of my table). Basically, when a button is clicked, all selected checkboxes should be disabled.

I am able to get the indices of selected rows by using

```
table.column(0).checkboxes.selected();
```

But I'm not quite sure how to proceed from there, aka how to reference the checkbox elements. I've tried using

```
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]')
```

to get all checkboxse, but I wasn't able to use prop('disabled', false). For example, when I do

```
checkboxes[1].prop('disabled', false)
```

I get the "prop is not a function" error.

Could someone help me here?

Answer (score 1):

`checkboxes` isn't a jQuery object so it doesn't have a `prop` function.  Use `var checkboxes = $('input[type=checkbox]')` instead and see if that works.  Also, you probably want to set disabled to `true`, not `false`.

Comment: That didn't eliminate the error. However, I found that I could directly access the property by doing checkboxes[1].disabled = true, and that worked for me.

Comment: If you figured it out - great. If not, go ahead and post a snippet of your html and JS and I'll continue to help as best I can